# How make nvim NOT to remove trailing spaces?

Tags: neovim

There is a not-so-well formatted text file (c# code). Some lines in this file contain trailing spaces.

I do not want to fix these trailing spaces (let 'git blame' blame those who wrote these lines!)

However, when I open the file with nvim and save the file all the trailing spaces are gone.
(After I open the file trailing spaces are present, but after ':w' they are gone)

This is very strange because:

1. even if I open the file with '-b' and/or '--clean' options nvim removes trailing spaces. (according to help '--clean' option tells nvim not to load my rc or any 'external' plugins, built-in plugins are still loaded)
2. if I open the file with '-u NONE' option nvim does not remove trailing spaces (according to help, even built-in plugins are not loaded in this case)
3. if I move the file to a different directory nvim does not remove trailing spaces (!!!). Looks like that spaces are removed if the file remains in the same git repo - when I move the file to a different git repo and spaces are not removed.
4. Looks like the current working directory doesn't affect this behavior.

NVIM v0.9.1, OS - Windows.

Any ideas what is going on and how to suppress this feature?

Comment: "I do not want to fix these trailing spaces (let 'git blame' blame those who wrote these lines!)" - or you could follow the *boy scout rule* and fix whitespace throughout the project. Let `git blame` credit you for improving the project for everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your file is in a repository that contains an [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) file with the `trim_trailing_whitespace` setting set to true. [Neovim will detect this file](https://neovim.io/doc/user/editorconfig.html), and then apply the contained rules to your files, removing the trailing whitespace on save.

You can disable this feature by adding the following line to your Neovim config:

```
vim.g.editorconfig = false
```

...or you can find the `.editorconfig` file which is causing this behaviour and remove the `trim_trailing_whitespace` setting.